# Proto-Uralic *kämä vs Akkadian kamūnu

Tags: etymology, uralic, akkadian

The English Wikipedia article for "cumin" mentions

> All of these ultimately derive from Akkadian  (kamūnu).

In Hungarian, caraway seeds are called köménymag, keménymag where the word "kemény" is said to derive from *kämä (“hard, firm”).

But, as we know, caraway seeds are quite hard. Is this just a strange overlapping of two words deriving from very different roots or is the Proto Uralic word influenced by the Akkadian one?

Comment: Hi, could you refine (add detail to) the title so that more people understand what the ultimate question is?

Comment: to the close voters, it is language specific *grammar* and *usage* questions that are off-topic, not etymologies. The fact we've got a specific tag for it, and the huge number of questions on this topic that haven't been closed make that clear

Comment: @purlupar I thought it is clear...? There is a single question in the whole post ...? Not sure what it is missing.

Comment: My advice was because I saw many people voted it down, me not included (the opposite is true: I tagged it). You can proceed whichever way you want, I can't help any further.

Comment: This question seems perfectly fine to me, but I agree you ought to change the title. “Hungarian _kömény_ vs _kemény_” isn’t really what the question is about at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I changed the title.

Comment: Just because the etymology tag exists doesn't mean that most etymology questions are on-topic. We've had lots of discussions on Meta, and I still maintain that we should only allow etymology questions which are about systematic issues. This just seems like a question about an arbitrary word and coincidental sound similarities.

Comment: @curiousdannii True, though this question in particular actually gets at a systemic issue imo ("what does it mean when a Wanderwort is popularly associated with another word in a language" → "almost always a folk etymology"), so I'd leave it open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to add a bit to Adam's excellent answer:

"Cumin" is what's called a **Wanderwort** or **wander-word**: it's a word associated with some sort of trade good, which spreads from language to language along with the thing it describes. A famous modern example is "tea"; almost every language in the world now refers to the drink with a word that looks like either "tea" or "chai".

This is why the word for "cumin" looks so similar in everything from English to Sumerian (*<sup>Ú</sup>gamun*). The details of how it spread aren't entirely clear, but Akkadian probably borrowed it from Sumerian, Greek possibly from Akkadian, Latin from Greek, French from Latin, English from French, and so on. And Sumerian likely picked it up from some other language that was never written down and has been lost to the mists of time.

One other trait of Wanderworter, though, is that they don't have a clear etymology in most languages (because they're borrowed as complete, opaque units). So *folk etymologies* are common, linking the words to other things within the language. That's how *kömeny* is associated with **kämä*. But etymologically, most likely, the name *kömeny* was borrowed from whichever other people were trading the spice, with no other connections within Uralic.

Comment: On the other hand, because of how sound changes work, there's a significant chance that the word and its derivational base would remain recognizably similar, even if both were borrowed but from the same source. The onus of proof, though, lies on the accuser, and there's no obvious way how Sumerian should get it from what would then have been Ugric or even Proto-Uralic. Since the area of Hungary has a history with Huns and Turks, and Turks are literally called *Kümmeltürken* today in derogitory registers, that's where I would look next.

Comment: BTW, as a word of note, we see various terms retrofit to sacral languages, e.g. in neo-Latin. *gamun* is attested from the Ur III period onwards, that is ca. 4kya, when Akkadian already too place; attested eight times, in overall three different spellings, of which the older one can be seen there [1](http://psd.museum.upenn.edu/epsd/psl/img/popup/Obic.png). I can make out that the latter one cited above is composed of *ga [MILK]* and *mun [SALT]* (as orthographic spelling, surely), but found none for the former, so far, which probably doesn't matter anyway

Answer (score 7):

> ... is said to derive from ...

This is **folk etymology**.  In a case like this, where it's a similar sounding word in many unrelated languages across a region, you should be especially skeptical.

The Wiktionary entry for *kömény*:

> A wanderword, arrived to Hungarian possibly via German, but a West Slavic borrowing cannot be excluded, either. Compare German Kümmel, Greek κύμινο (kýmino), from Latin cuminum, from Ancient Greek κύμινον (kúminon).

It's common enough that a folk etymology or subconscious confusion with known words or native morphemes has a real *influence* on the pronunciation, spelling or senses of a word - and that may be the case here - but that's a very different than *derivation*.